# How to calculate the perimeter of an image contour in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to find the perimeter value of image contours to be used as a feature to classify the images.

How can I calculate the perimeter in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can binarize your image (for instance with [`graythresh`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html?searchHighlight=graythresh) or any other thresholding method) and then use the `Perimeter` property of [`regionprops`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html?searchHighlight=regionprops#inputarg_properties).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have easier access to the coordinates of the region boundary, you may find [`bwboundaries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) very useful.